# Recognizing text on screen with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ocr, graphics2d

I am building a program that records a "kill feed" in the top right of a full-screen game and performs two actions as a result:

1. Update a counter I've painted to the screen with an always-on-top, transparent window that represents the number of players alive on each team (in the style of "2 v 1"), and
2. render a "hitmarker" graphic when my in-game username appears in the killfeed, indicating that I've killed my opponent

I've been programming in Java for three years, but I still don't know how to achieve this. I am able to use Graphics2D to paint graphics such as a "hitmarker" and draw strings such as the player count I mentioned above. However, I do not know how to recognize colors or text on screen, aside from Java's built-in Java's built-in [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)'s `getPixelColor()` method (which I've never used before).

My best guess is to use `java.util.Robot`'s `createScreenCapture()` method to save an image of the screen 60 times per second and do some OCR magic to recognize my username, then perform the two actions I detailed above.

Because I'm relatively inexperienced, specific and detailed answers would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I know it's not feasible to save the screen 60 times a second. My intention was for another method to be proposed. Also, as clarification, I am drawing over a game, and reading a killfeed that is a part of the game, not my program. I'm not rendering the feed, just the player counter and hitmarker (killmarker) because it's not a feature of the game like the killfeed is.

Comment: it's not a good idea to paint information on the screen and read these information back again. create a model that stores these information and read the infos from the **model**, not from the screen

Comment: Are you trying to paint on top of a different program?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get better responses and fewer downvotes, first go through the [quick tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), then read the [help], especially [What's On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic),[ask] and [What Not To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and then post your question according to these guidelines.

Comment: why you need to get username from screen? you yourself painted it to screen, so keeping it at a global variable, you can use it for further needs.

Comment: "Save the screen 60 times pr second".... Your game will most likely be unplayable.

Comment: I've updated the question to better clarify and to answer some questions.